# Java's HttpURLConnection seems to append 0018 character in request?

Tags: java, http, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send an image via HTTP.

I've tested it via Chrome, using Wireshark to see the details of the request. The separation between the headers and the multipart content is `\r\n`.

My implementation, in Java, however, seems to have a separation being `\r\n` and the character `0018`, which according to [FileFormat.info](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0018/index.htm) is the `CANCEL` character.

I'm using [Java's HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (accessed from Kotlin but that shouldn't be the problem), here is the sample of the code, used to write to file content:

```
val endl = "\r\n"
val hyphens = "--"
val boundary = "----${System.currentTimeMillis()}---"

// conn is an HttpURLConnection
val output = conn.outputStream
val writer = DataOutputStream(output)
writer.flush()

writer.writeUTF(hyphens + boundary + endl) // first time writing
writer.writeUTF("Content-Disposition: form-data; name: [REDACTED]" + endl)
writer.writeUTF("Content-Type: [REDACTED]" + endl)
writer.writeUTF(endl)

// [REDACTED: Writing the contents of the file]

writer.writeUTF(endl)
writer.writeUTF(hyphens + boundary + hyphens + endl)

writer.flush()
writer.close()
```

(the complete code for this sample can be found [here](https://phabricator.wildfyre.net/D191#change-MDZEBfcBxyvH), lines 99-144)

The character `0018` is inserted right before that code sample, and right after the headers (which are written using `HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty` so I don't believe they can be the problem... just in case, you can find that code [here](https://phabricator.wildfyre.net/D191#change-MDZEBfcBxyvH), lines 64-91).

Here is the beginning of the request's body:

```
------1544883782650---
DContent-Disposition: form-data; name: "avatar"; filename: "wf.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

(you can see the CANCEL character at the beginning of the first line, right before the boundary).

Compared to the request made by Chrome:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryAhYDuYuz5IuXB95v
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="discord.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

For some reason Chrome doesn't have those weird characters.

Note. I just noticed that Chrome uses `form-data; name="avatar"; filename="discord.png"` and I use `form-data; name: "avatar"; filename: "wf.png"`; I edited it and re-tested, that's not the problem.

Comment: On the last examples, SO doesn't display the weird characters; but they are included. In the editing window you can see them

Comment: I can't see the wierd character in the editing window (Android Chrome browser) but I see there's a 'D' character before the `Content-Disposition` header.

Comment: It's part of the weirdly-inserted characters. I did not add this 'D', as you can see in the code sample above. I don't understand where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) of `writeUTF` says:

> First, two bytes are written to the output stream as if by the writeShort method giving the number of bytes to follow. This value is the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the string. Following the length, each character of the string is output, in sequence, using the modified UTF-8 encoding for the character.

What you see at the beginning of each line is probably the 2 characters marking the number of bytes to follow.

I think `DataOutputStream` is not ideal for your use case. Use the plain `write(byte[] bytes)` method of the `OutputStream` after converting your header `String`s with `s.getBytes("UTF-8")`.

Comment: `s.getBytes()` means loading the full file into the cache though, is there a way to do it through a Stream ?

Comment: `getBytes` is only needed to write the headers to `conn.outputStream` (for which you used `writeUTF` before). After the headers you can use e.g. [Files.copy(path, conn.outputStream)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.io.OutputStream)) to copy the contents of the file to the output stream.

Answer (score 1):

From the javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF-java.lang.String- with emphasis added:

> **First, two bytes are written** to the output stream as if by the writeShort method **giving the number of bytes to follow**. This value is the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the string. Following the length, each character of the string is output, in sequence, using the modified UTF-8 encoding for the character. ...

`Data{Input,Output}Stream` are not intended for text and should not be used for text. MIME in general, and multipart in particular, is mostly text or at least text-compatible to make it compatible with email which traditionally was text, although HTTP is agnostic (it supports both text and binary).